# how to select records with specific value/condition in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables STUDENT, SUBJECT and GRADE.

STUDENT

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| student_id | first_name |  last_name |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          0 | Arthur     | Pain       |
|          1 | Richard    | Gordon     |
|          2 | Jennifer   | Adelaide   |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

SUBJECT

```
+------------+--------------+
| subject_id | subject_name |
+------------+--------------+
|        001 | Math         |
|        002 | Science      |
|        003 | English      |
+------------+--------------+
```

GRADE

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+
| student_id  | subject_id  |  grade |  
+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 0           | 001         | A      |  
| 0           | 002         | B      |  
| 0           | 003         | A      |  
| 1           | 001         | B      |  
| 1           | 002         | A      |  
| 1           | 003         | F      |  
| 2           | 001         | A      |  
| 2           | 002         | B      | 
| 2           | 003         | B      |
+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

I have tried the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM student st WHERE EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 FROM grade g WHERE st.student_id = g.student_id AND g.grade IN ('A','B');
```

I want to select the students with grades only 'A' OR 'B'.

Comment: try replacing "1" with `*`; you can use Grade directly instead g.grade

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar Why would you replace `1` with `*`????  You don't need all columns.

Comment: you would need all columns

Answer (score 0):

What about simply adding a NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
 FROM student st
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM grade g 
                WHERE st.student_id = g.student_id
                  AND g.grade IN ('A','B'))
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM grade g
                WHERE st.student_id = g.student_id
                  AND g.grade IN ('C', 'D', 'F'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT *
  FROM student s
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM grade g
            WHERE g.student_id = s.student_id AND grade NOT IN ('A', 'B'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the joins to connects the multiple tables

```
select s.*,g.* from student as s
inner join GRADE as g on g.student_id=s.student_id
inner join SUBJECT as sj on sj.subject_id = g.subject_id
where g.grade in ('A','B')
```

i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT 
LEFT JOIN GRADE ON STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = GRADE.STUDENT_ID
LEFT JOIN SUBJECT ON GRADE.SUBJECT_ID = SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID 
WHERE GRADE.GRADE IN ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Not In :

```
SELECT * FROM student st WHERE student_id not in 
       (SELECT student_id FROM grade g WHERE grade = 'F');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM STUDENT
 WHERE student_id IN ( SELECT student_id
                         FROM GRADE
                        WHERE grade IN ( 'A', 'B' ) );
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id, first_name, last_name
  FROM STUDENT NATURAL JOIN GRADE
 WHERE grade IN ( 'A', 'B' );
```